# Using special characters in SQL as string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar (500)

SET @myVariable = 'select distinct b.*,v.vertrag_id,v.VersicherungsscheinNummer 
from CRM_Wifo_GmbH.dbo.vertrag_168 v,temp_universa b 
where v.VersicherungsscheinNummer like '%' + b.vsnr + '% 
and v.gesellschaft_id in('59','66')'
```

I have to set the value of this type in a variable. How could I do this? Is it possible? USING **' '** sign in a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to escape the single quote `'` using 2 single quotes instead `''`

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar (500)
SET @myVariable = 
N'select distinct b.*,v.vertrag_id,v.VersicherungsscheinNummer 
  from CRM_Wifo_GmbH.dbo.vertrag_168 v,temp_universa b 
  where v.VersicherungsscheinNummer like ''%'' + b.vsnr + ''% 
  and v.gesellschaft_id in(''59'',''66'')'
```

I am also using `N'`, so that I can span the string on multiple lines

Comment: WOW!! Great!!! this worked. and thanks a lot. i will accept it as right answere after 11 mins :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solutions :

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar (500)
SET @myVariable = 'select distinct b.*,v.vertrag_id,v.VersicherungsscheinNummer from CRM_Wifo_GmbH.dbo.vertrag_168 v,temp_universa b where v.VersicherungsscheinNummer like ' + char(39) + '%' + char(39) + ' + b.vsnr + ' + char(39) + '% and v.gesellschaft_id in(' + char(39) + '59' + char(39) + ',' + char(39) + '66' + char(39) + ')'
```

But i suggesst you, using 2 single quotes.